# FB.PublishInstall doesn't work in Unity

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I've tried FB.PublishInstall on several iOS devices for the test application. Sometimes it doesn't make any response at all (doesn't call callback), in other cases it returns error:

    `{
      "code":400,
      "body":
      {
        "error":
        {
          "message":"Unsupported post request",
          "type":"GraphMethodException",
          "code":100
        }
      }
    }`

Tried on iPad 2 (iOS 6.0.1), iPhone 4s (iOS 5.1.1), iPod 4 (iOS 6.0.1).
On Facebook side application is just created, no custom settings were done, maybe it's the case.

Facebook Unity SDK from 2014-04-01.

Attachments:

1. [Info.plist file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1lezsz5bzkmqir/Info.plist)

Comment: Did you configurate plist with appID?

Comment: There is CFBundleURLTypes and FacebookAppID entries in the Info.plist. I've attached the Info.plist to the description above. Maybe something is missing, please let me know if any.

Comment: Hm, seems like all correct